# Specifying start time and end time of the section of the video to be cut in Camtasia

Tags: windows-7, camtasia

Is there any way to specify the start time and end time of the section of the video to be cut in [Camtasia 8.3](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html), instead of having to manual move the green and red sliders?

[image]

I use Camtasia 8.3.0 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to specify the start time and end time of the section of the video to be cut in Camtasia 8.3, instead of having to manual move the green and red sliders.